# Not able to export the cer file to .p12 file, option is disabled

Tags: ios

I have created the new distribution certificate in apple portal from my keychainAccess->Preferences->Request a Certificate from Certificate Authority. After installing the .cer file, i am not able to get the private key, basically p12 option is disabled while exporting the certificate. Tried multiple times, by revoking the certificate and repeating the same steps, but still facing the problem.
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPM15.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRU7l.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change keychains from `System` to `Login`

[image]

Then Try to Export items.

Also check while installing `.cer` file add to Login instead of System.

Comment: and also important to choose 'MY certificates'